# creating server with Microsoft Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am working with a django project and I want to connect it to local server. I downloaded the Microsoft Server Management Studio but got lost on how to create a server and database?

If I am not wrong the object explorer tab only lets you connect to existing server. Is that right? If not how do I create a new server and database in SMSS?

Also I have imported a .bacpac file from the azure cloud and want to duplicate that cloud database in my local machine so that I don't mess up the actual database on cloud while testing. (I followed this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475306/how-do-i-copy-sql-azure-database-to-my-local-development-server)

So how do I create a server/database on local machine using SMSS and load it with the .bacpac file to backup my django site?

Would appreciate the help

Answer (score 6):

SSMS is only a development and management tool.  To install a SQL Server instance you need do download and install SQL Server.  EG [SQL Server Developer Edition](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853016).  See: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/

Or provision a SQL Server database in the cloud with Azure SQL Database.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/services/sql-database/